# How to select a part of a picture WP 8.1

Tags: image, resize, windows-phone-8.1

On my WP 8.1, I'm allowing the user to pick up a picture as his profile picture. Actually I have some problems with resolution of the image. So the solution would be to display to picture full size and let him select the part of the picture that he wants to display as you can do on Facebook for the cover picture for example... I cannot get any guidelines for that. Maybe some of you have met that need and could give me some advises ?!

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Did you try out this sample? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Save-Edited-Picture-16d910c4

Comment: Nop, I didn't event know that action was named "crop". Will check it out ! Thanks for the link, ll come back with feedbacks about it !